# how to get the download duration of a audio tag in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, typescript, nestjs

[image]

On the streaming website, there is a section that shows you how much the video or audio you are watching is downloaded, I want to get the downloaded duration of my audio tag in React, but I don't know how!

this is my Nest.js code that streams the musics:

```js
    @Get()
    stream_music(@Req() req: Request, @Res() res: Response) {
        try {
            const path = './musics/big.mp3';

            res.set('content-type', 'audio/mp3');
            res.set('accept-ranges', 'bytes');

            const range = req.headers.range;
            const stat = fs.statSync(path);
            const fileSize = stat.size;

            let startTime
            let endTime

            if (range) {
                // Handle byte-range requests
                const parts = rangeParser(fileSize, range);
                const start = parts[0].start;
                const end = parts[0].end;
                const chunkSize = (end - start) + 1;

                const file = fs.createReadStream(path, { start, end });
                const headers = {
                    'Content-Range': `bytes ${start}-${end} /${fileSize}`,
                    'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes',
                    'Content-Length': chunkSize,
                    'Content-Type': 'video/mp4',
                };

                // file.on('data', (chunk) => {
                //     if (!startTime) {
                //         startTime = Date.now();
                //     }
                //     endTime = Date.now();

                //     const duration = endTime - startTime;
                //     console.log(`duration: ${duration}`);
                // });

                res.writeHead(206, headers);
                file.pipe(res);
            } else {
                const stream = fs.createReadStream(path)

                stream.on('data', (chunk) => {
                    if (!startTime) {
                        startTime = Date.now();
                    }
                    endTime = Date.now();

                    const duration = endTime - startTime;
                    console.log(req.headers.range);
                    console.log(`duration: ${duration}`);

                    res.write(chunk);
                });

                stream.on('error', () => {
                    res.sendStatus(404);
                });

                stream.on('end', () => {
                    const duration = endTime - startTime;
                    console.log(`finish duration: ${duration}`);
                    startTime = ""
                    endTime = ""
                    res.end();
                });
            }

        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
```

and this is my react code that renders the music from the my nest.js:

```js
export default function Page() {
    const audioPlayer: any = useRef()

    const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);

    const [currentSong] = useState('http://localhost:4001/api/music');

    const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);
    const [volume, setVolume] = useState(30);
    const [mute, setMute] = useState(true);

    const [elapsed, setElapsed] = useState(0);
    const [duration, setDuration] = useState(0);
    const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (audioPlayer) {
            audioPlayer.current.volume = volume / 100;
        }


        if (isPlaying) {
            setInterval(() => {
                const _duration = Math.floor(audioPlayer?.current?.duration);
                const _elapsed = Math.floor(audioPlayer?.current?.currentTime);

                setDuration(_duration);
                setElapsed(_elapsed);
            }, 100);
        }

    }, [
        volume, isPlaying
    ]);

    function formatTime(time: number) {
        if (time && !isNaN(time)) {
            const minutes = Math.floor(time / 60) < 10 ? `0${Math.floor(time / 60)}` : Math.floor(time / 60);
            const seconds = Math.floor(time % 60) < 10 ? `0${Math.floor(time % 60)}` : Math.floor(time % 60);

            return `${minutes}:${seconds}`;
        }
        return '00:00';
    }

    const togglePlay = () => {
        if (!isPlaying) {
            audioPlayer.current.play()
        } else {
            audioPlayer.current.pause()
        }
        setIsPlaying(prev => !prev)
    }

    const toggleForward = () => {
        audioPlayer.current.currentTime += 10;
    }

    const toggleBackward = () => {
        audioPlayer.current.currentTime -= 10;
    }

    const toggleSkipForward = () => {
        audioPlayer.current.play();
    }

    const toggleSkipBackward = () => {
        audioPlayer.current.play();
    }

    function VolumeBtns() {
        return mute
            ? <VolumeOffIcon sx={{ color: 'lime', '&:hover': { color: 'white' } }} onClick={() => setMute(!mute)} />
            : volume <= 20 ? <VolumeMuteIcon sx={{ color: 'lime', '&:hover': { color: 'white' } }} onClick={() => setMute(!mute)} />
                : volume <= 75 ? <VolumeDownIcon sx={{ color: 'lime', '&:hover': { color: 'white' } }} onClick={() => setMute(!mute)} />
                    : <VolumeUpIcon sx={{ color: 'lime', '&:hover': { color: 'white' } }} onClick={() => setMute(!mute)} />
    }

    return (
        <Div>
            <audio
                src={currentSong}
                ref={audioPlayer}
                muted={mute}
            />
            <CustomPaper sx={{ height: '100%', pt: 10 }}>
                <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
                    <Stack direction='row' spacing={1}
                        sx={{
                            display: 'flex',
                            justifyContent: 'flex-start',
                            width: '25%',
                            alignItems: 'center'
                        }}
                    >
                        <VolumeBtns />

                        <SoundPSlider
                            min={0}
                            max={80}
                            value={volume}
                            onChange={(e: any, v: any) => setVolume(v)}
                            marks={marks}
                            valueLabelDisplay="on"
                        />
                    </Stack>

                    <Stack direction='row' spacing={1}
                        sx={{
                            display: 'flex',
                            width: '40%',
                            alignItems: 'center'
                        }}>

                        <SkipPreviousIcon
                            sx={{
                                color: 'black',
                                '&:hover': { color: 'white' }
                            }}
                            onClick={toggleSkipBackward}
                            disabled={true}
                        />

                        <FastRewindIcon sx={{ color: 'lime', '&:hover': { color: 'white' } }} onClick={toggleBackward} />

                        {!isPlaying
                            ? <PlayArrowIcon fontSize={'large'} sx={{ color: 'black', '&:hover': { color: 'white' } }} onClick={togglePlay} />
                            : <PauseIcon fontSize={'large'} sx={{ color: 'black', '&:hover': { color: 'white' } }} onClick={togglePlay} />
                        }


                        <FastForwardIcon sx={{ color: 'black', '&:hover': { color: 'white' } }} onClick={toggleForward} />
                        <SkipNextIcon sx={{ color: 'black', '&:hover': { color: 'white' } }} onClick={toggleSkipForward} />
                    </Stack>

                    <Stack sx={{
                        display: 'flex',
                        justifyContent: 'flex-end',
                    }} />
                </Box>
                
                <Stack spacing={3} direction='row' sx={{
                    display: 'flex',
                    alignItems: 'center'
                }}>
                    <Typography sx={{ color: 'lime' }}>{formatTime(elapsed)}</Typography>
                    <SoundPSlider
                        value={elapsed}
                        max={duration}
                        marks={[
                            {
                                value: 0
                            },
                            {
                                value: progress
                            },
                            {
                                value: duration
                            }
                        ]}
                        aria-label="Temperature"
                        onChange={(e: any, v: any) => {
                            audioPlayer.current.currentTime = e.target.value
                        }}
                    />

                    <Typography sx={{ color: 'lime' }}>{formatTime(duration - elapsed)}</Typography>
                </Stack>
            </CustomPaper>
        </Div>
    )
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Audio_and_video_delivery/buffering_seeking_time_ranges `const bufferedTimeRanges = audio.buffered;`